# abline() function not working in R 3.2.0

Tags: r, plot

While using

```
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt,mpg)
```

till here it's working fine but when I am trying to add a line to the graph by the below code :

```
abline(lm (mpg~ wt))
```

I am getting an error :

> **Error in x * x : non-numeric argument to binary operator.**

Answer (score 6):

First off, don't do `attach()`.

Second, you cannot do `abline()` unless a `plot()` has come first.

So try this:

```
plot(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars)
abline(lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars))
```

which produces the graph below.
[image]